# Using a class on a multi-page form

Tags: php, class, oop

I would like to use Classes in my next website. Part of the site involves a multi-page profile form. The visitor fills in their name, submits this and then fills in their date of birth, submits this and then adds some text.

When the first form is submitted I will instantiate the class and update the database etc but when the visitor submits the next form do I need to declare another "new" class or does it stay instantiated?

What is the recommended way of achieving this kind of behaviour (ie not using classes for this / using sessions to hold the data / instantiating all classes on each page refresh / etc)

Thanks for some direction with this.

Comment: php is stateless, nothing is kept in memory between requests. So you will need to instantiate a new class if its needed, and save data somewhere, either DB or sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PHP is stateless any classes you initiate only exist for that one page. If you create an instance with data in, it will only exist on that page. If you want it to exist on multiple pages then you will need to reload it on every page.

For what you're describing it would seem that you would first gather all the data, storing the users answers in session between each page, and then once you have all the answers initiate your class to do whatever it is you want to with your data.

Answer (score 1):

Php data is unset after next request exept for persistant data like session and etc... .

To answer your question: 
If this case is on one request and the scope of the variable is ok you could use the same variable(and instance) of the object.
If not, you should make a new instance.